# How to decide if SQS should be used with Lambda or not?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-ses

I have a scenario where messages gets published to SNS and my lambda wants to listen to messages in SNS topic. Sometimes, I see there is a SQS queue added as a subscriber to SNS Topic. And lambda polls messages from SQS queue. Also, sometimes, lambda directly subscribes to SNS topic.

How do we decide which strategy to use when? Please provide some suggestions.

Comment: By polling an SQS queue, you can read messages sequentially. By subscribing to SNS topic, the messages will be processed in parallel. Each implementation depends on what we want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQS:

- When the application will fetch the messages [Message polling]
- SQS to store the message[max 14 days]

Use SNS:

- When the application has an endpoint to receive the message
- You don't need to save / store messages